# error installing PEAR (wrong dir)

Tags: php, pear, freebsd

The error I am receiving is:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'pages/mail/config.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/share/pear') in login-exec.php on line 4
```

But when installing PEAR I made a boo-boo and put it in the wrong directory:

```
php pyrus.phar install -r /usr/local/etc/ pear/PEAR-1.9.5
```

I should of used:

```
php pyrus.phar install -r /usr/local/share/ pear/PEAR-1.9.5
```

I was able to switch the config of the php directory with

```
pear config-set php_dir /usr/local/share/pear
```

but when actually implementing the change, I run out of memory

pear upgrade --force
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 49152 bytes) in /usr/local/etc/php/pearcmd.php on line 148

I even cloned my 768mb VPS to a 4 gig unit and even after adjusting the memory in the php.ini, phar blows the memory up

I tried:

```
memory_limit = 1024
```

and

```
memory_limit = -1
```

I tried a symlink and 'include_path = ".:/usr/local/etc/' in the .ini, but apache cannot reach the PEAR structure in that directory so I am pretty sure the app must be relocated.

There in nothing in FreeBSD that will eat 2 gigs of memory except for bad code.

How to I fully delete pear so that is will no long default to the bad directory at reinstall?
or
How do I manually move PEAR to the proper directory structure avoiding a memory flood from bad engineering?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two installers; `pyrus` and `pear`. Use only one to install your libs.